# Editing of Dynamic fields in OTRS

Tags: otrs

Background: I've installed and currently maintaining a OTRS v4.0 system.
Currently, I've added some [Dynamic fields](https://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/3.2/en/html/dynamicfields.html) to it i.e whenever user creates a ticket he sees the usual fields like title, body of message + the dynamic fields while creating a ticket in the system. 2 of the dynamic fields are 'Start time' and 'End time'.

Following is my problem: Now, while creating the ticket suppose user doesn't specifies these dynamic fields and creates the ticket and later on he wants to edit the ticket and specify the 'End time' i.e. wants to edit and update the ticket.
I could only get([from OTRS Admin manual](https://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/4.0/en/html/index.html)) that I can change the status of the ticket from 'Open' -> 'Closed' or 'forward' the ticket to another person or 'move the ticket' to another queue. However, I cannot find if I can edit the ticket(as mentioned above) and update it without creating a new ticket with same details and new 'End date'.

Is their any way out for my problem? Or OTRS strictly doesn't supports this?

Any workaround is also welcome! ;)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can edit Ticket's dynamic fields.

Just a quick example ( based on OTRS 3.x but the idea is the same )

1) Open your Admin->SysConfig and search for   Ticket::Frontend::AgentTicketNote###DynamicField entry.

2) Open the container settings tab and add your dynamic field to the list ( see image 1 )[image: Notes settings]

3) Open the ticket list and press the Note button ( Image 2 )
[image: Notes Button]

4) In the Note window you can add a Note to the ticket, change some settings ( priority, service, criticality etc... ) and definitely change your desired dynamic field ( Image 3 )
[image: Notes window]

Smile,
A.

Comment: It worked. Thank you for detailed and step-wise answer! :)